# Object reference not set to an instance of an object MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, 3-tier

I'm new to MVC working on 3-tier MVC project and i am using a ready database.

now i need to write a query using linq in Business Layer to bring list of doctors like this :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using DoctorsSheet.DataAccess;

namespace DoctorsSheet.Business
{
    class Doctor : IDoctor
    {
        DoctorsSheetDBEntities db = new DoctorsSheetDBEntities();

        public IQueryable<Doctors> GetDoctors()
        {
            var doctors = from d in db.Doctors
                          select d;

            return doctors.AsQueryable<Doctors>();
        }
     }
}
```

and when i call GetDoctors() from DoctorsController 
it tell me Object reference not set to an instance of an object

this is the Controller :

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var doctors = obj.GetDoctors().AsQueryable<Doctors>();
    return View(doctors);
}
```

please help me how to fix it.

Comment: on which variable you are getting this error?

Comment: You don't need to cast to Queryable after doing `GetDoctors()` because you already cast to Queryable in the method.

Comment: on variable doctors in the ActionResult @ramiramilu

Comment: @Sippy if you mean like this :
var doctors = obj.GetDoctors();
i did it and still not working

Comment: What's `obj` in your controller?

Comment: `class Doctor` should be `public class Doctor` and you should declare `var obj = new Doctor()`

Comment: its obj from IDoctors (its an interface in business layer) that i defined in controller like this :

    public class DoctorsController : Controller
    {
            IDoctor obj;

Comment: `IDoctor obj;` it should be initiated somewhere right? where you are doing that?

Comment: @ramiramilu thaaank yoou 
i'm feeling stupid
i did what you told me
i forget to set it public !!

really thanks guys :)

Comment: Glad I am helpful, posted the same as answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your class `public` -

```
public class Doctor : IDoctor
```

And then initiate `obj` variable as shown below and then use `obj`.

```
IDoctor obj = new Doctor();
```

NOTE: As @Sippy explained there is no need for you to use `GetDoctors().AsQueryable<Doctors>();`.